# Selecting a point programmatically on stockchart from HighCharts library in GWT (Also in native JS)

Tags: javascript, gwt, highcharts

I'm using Stockchart from HighCharts API for GWT. I want to select a point when clicking on a button.

I have something like this:

```
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

        System.out.println("Clicked + i ." + i + "- >" + points[i].getX() ) ;
        chart.getSeries()[0].getPoints()[i].select(true, false);
        select(true, false);
        i++;
        if (i == 4) {
            i = 0;
        }
    }
```

Now, this works well for Highchart graphic, but for StockChart (same API, just different chart object), it doesn't work. Doesn't Stock chart support 
this functionality? Maybe due to the navigation? Please help.

**EDIT:**
I also tested both chart types, and this is the result. It seems to me that, either the StockChart doesn't support this functionality (maybe beacuse of naviagation options), or it may need some extra configuration. Here are the tests:
[Stock test](http://jsfiddle.net/sURzE/9)
[HighChart test](http://jsfiddle.net/sURzE/8)

Thank you

Comment: Is documented as being fully supported in the base highstock documentation.  Presumably if its not supported its an issue with the GWT shell.

Comment: Ok, but I tryed testing on JS, and it didnt' work as well. In these two examples, only the chart type is changed, and on HighChart it works, and StockChart doesn't. :\
Stock: http://jsfiddle.net/sURzE/9/ - HighChart: http://jsfiddle.net/sURzE/8/

Comment: please see my updated question better formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to enable Markers.

Try adding this:

```
 Marker marker = new Marker();
 marker.setEnabled(true);

 SeriesPlotOptions spo = new SeriesPlotOptions();
 spo.setMarker(marker);

 Series series1 = chart.createSeries()
 .setPlotOptions(spo)
```